# Angular ngFor change detection with trackBy in Safari vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, safari

I have an application connected with firebase, it fetches the whole object whenever any change happens to it.

Lets say I have an object like this:

```
{
    count: 0,
    media: [{
      src: 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
    }, {
      src: 'http://placehold.it/350x250'
    }]
  };
```

whenever the count increases, I get the whole object from the backend with same `src` values.
Here's what happens when the data binds with the view:

- Chrome: The images doesn't refresh since its the same `src`. (Expected behavior)
- Safari: The images reloads every time when the new object gets assigned.

I've also tried using `trackBy: media?.src` but getting the same result.

Is this an issue with Angular's `trackBy` or is it just how Safari works???

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cmg86jfTFxIzEDJNa8Yq?p=preview).

Comment: If the behavior is different in both browsers then I guess it is a behavior of the browser and not the library(Angular2), instead of assigning the whole new object you can try to `push` only the new items, then maybe you will avoid images reload

Comment: Pushing new objects is not a problem, but updating an existing object is where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `trackBy: Object?.property` is deprecated and using a tracking function `trackBy: trackByFn` works like a charm.

Though I think Chrome handles DOM changes more gracefully than Safari.